# How do I determine which traffic is routed through the VPN from the client side?

Tags: windows, vpn, routing

If I have a Cisco VPN client on my computer and I want to see if https or http traffic is routed through the VPN or not, how should I do this?  Can viewing the routing table tell me this information?  Preferably without the use of third party tools like wireshark, I would rather do this will Windows tools like netstat if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to darwish's suggestion to using `tracert`, you can do either of the following -

`1`. Execute `route print` in command prompt and see what the default gateway is. The default gateway is the one one which starts with `0.0.0.0` - and that line will tell you what gateway IP or interface is used as default route.

`2.` Just google `what is my ip` or visit [ifconfig.me](http://ifconfig.me), that will give you your public facing IP address. If you know which one is vpn and which one is your ISP's IP, then you should be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Amazing that I didn't bother to think of any of this, but it's the weekend and I am done with thinking for the week.  I did a whatismyip.con and saw my ISP in the results, assuming that my company doesnt use consumer grade ISP, I think it is save to say that http traffic is routed through my ISP unless of course the IP of the site resolves to one of the routes specified in the VPN routes that were added via the VPN client.

Answer (score 4):

Try using tracert to see the actual route for some host.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162326

If the traffic is indeed routed via the VPN, you should see the VPN gateway in the route list.